# Can cairo_surface possibly be attach on wl_shell_surface?

Tags: cairo, surface, wayland

I am using cairo_surface (cairo_surface_t) and wl_shell_surface to display an object on a Wayland client's surface. So could you distinguish between these surface types ? They are obligated to exist together, or separate types of surface. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.
[image]

Cairo surface is strong in drawing 2D object (example: text, shape ...)
Refer to https://www.cairographics.org/